# Where can I find some open source implementations of the Boids algorithm, for the iOs?

Tags: iphone, open-source, ios, boids

The question says it all: I'm looking for working, open source, implementations of algorithms (or derivatives there of) initially described in the Boids paper.

Comment: You might check out Apple's SpriteKit implementation of boids flocking behavior from WWDC 2014. Some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44235801/4376309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like most of the code out there was written before "Open Source" really meant anything. I [asked Mr Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=boids+algorithm):

- [Craig Reynolds's Boids page](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) has a bunch of links for various languages and some mostly-original Lisp. Embedding a Lisp interpreter should not be that hard.
- [Christopher Kline, C++, Not-For-Profit](http://www.behaviorworks.com/people/ckline/cornellwww/boid/boids.html). Licence terms for commercial apps negotiable with the author.
- [Tom Bak, Thong Chau, Visual C++/OpenGL/GLUT, no licence](http://www.thomasbak.com/boids/index.htm). You could try contacting them.
- [Robert Platt, VC++/D3D, no licence](http://www.navgen.com/3d_boids/index.html). You could try contacting him too.

You're unlikely to find anything specifically "for the iOS" (or even written in Objective-C), but C and C++ versions should be easy to port. .NET versions should be easy enough to run using MonoTouch.

Comment: Is the algorithm too old, for anyone to have attempted to implement something like it for the iOS? Are there more modern versions that are more likely to have an iOS implementation?

Comment: Algorithms are generally developed for a *language*, not a *platform*. Most people do not write algorithms for Objective-C since it's neither widely-used, fast, nor quick to write; however it's easy enough to run standard C or C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Chapter from Killer game programming in Java about Flocking Boids](http://books.google.com/books?id=dOz-UK8Fl_UC&lpg=PA607&ots=aepbYs_HjQ&dq=killer%20game%20programming%20boids&pg=PA592#v=onepage&q&f=false)